# IIS CLI generate applicationhost.config with site for my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2017

I have a C# solution with several projects, one of which is a web server run by IIS. I have set `<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>True</UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>` in the csproj file of that project.

When I open Visual Studio, it generates this in ~/Documents/IISExpress/config/applicationhost.config:

```
    <sites>
        <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <site name="SealingService" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\sehch\Documents\Paragon\ParagonCore\servers\SealingService\SealingService" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:61800:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
        <siteDefaults>
            <logFile logFormat="W3C" directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\Logs" />
            <traceFailedRequestsLogging directory="%IIS_USER_HOME%\TraceLogFiles" enabled="true" maxLogFileSizeKB="1024" />
        </siteDefaults>
        <applicationDefaults applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool" />
        <virtualDirectoryDefaults allowSubDirConfig="true" />
    </sites>
```

I want to be able to run my project with IIS Express from the command line (for build server integration testing purposes). How can I generate the `SealingService` site section of applicationhost.config from the command line (without opening Visual Studio)?

I have tried running

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"
```

in my solution folder, but it only generates the `WebSite1` section.

Comment: I think that's strictly a VS feature. Why do you want it to "be generated"? You can always put a copy of `applicationHost.config` in your repo and on CI machine, running IIS Express from command line to read that config file.

Comment: @LexLi I could do that, but how do I set different `physicalPath`s for local and CI machines? We want to be able to run the tests on demand locally too, ideally without changing a config file.

Comment: Leave an environment variable in the path, and then set it in your CI sequence to the exact folder, I think it should work.

Comment: @LexLi I have gotten that to work, thanks!

Comment: The file _doesn't exist_ by default. Its only generated by using Visual Studio, and it's not generated just from a build. It's only generated if you run the debugger with IIS Express. So to really run this from the command line, you need a way to generate a applicationHost.config file the same way VS does it. That's the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you want to do is to add the section you specified to the **~/Documents/IISExpress/config/applicationhost.config** file.

You can do this using the [AppCmd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) command line tool:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" add site /name:SealingService /bindings:"http/*:61800:localhost" /physicalPath:"C:\Users\sehch\Documents\Paragon\ParagonCore\servers\SealingService\SealingService"
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" set site /site.name:SealingService /[path='/'].applicationPool:Clr4IntegratedAppPool
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\appcmd.exe" set site /site.name:SealingService /+bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:44300:localhost']
```

With the first command we **create the site**, set its **http binding** and its **physical path**; with the second one we set its **application pool** with the desired one; and with the third one we add the **https binding**.

If you use the x86 version of IIS Express, you find AppCmd in **C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\appcmd.exe**

Comment: This looks like it will edit the file, but what about generating the file in the first place?

Comment: @ScottH you can run iisexpress.exe to generate the file in first place

Comment: How can this file be generated in an arbitrary location, such as how visual studio generates the file under it's .vs user directory?

Comment: To create the file starting with nothing, copy the template from `<IIS-directory>/config/templates/PersonalWebServer/applicationhost.config` and use the argument `/apphostconfig:<path>` when executing `appcmd.exe`. Note that the file already has a site entry with `id="1"`.